# How to rename multiple file input files? in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Changing the name of files that go into a certain directory? This is my code;

```
$upload_files = $_FILES['files'];  

            // Inicia o array dos dados que serão inseridos
            $conf2 = array();

            // Varre o array com info. dos arquivos
            for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($upload_files); $i++) {

                // Nome do arquivo em cada elemento
                $new_name = $upload_files[$i]['name'];


                //Configure upload.
                $conf2[] = array(
                    "file_name" => $new_name,
                    "upload_path"   => './public/uploads/album/'. $past_date .'/'. $pasta .'/',
                    "allowed_types" => "mp3",
                    "max_size"  => "2194304000"
                );

                $this->upload->initialize($conf2);              
            }
```

I am using the class https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload
Sorry my bad inglish!

Comment: on conf2, what for you create array from array ?

Comment: multiply files rename